# How to reconstruct a Java sub class from XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-parsing

I will have a XML with following structure,

```
<xml>
<Header><Type>..</Type>...</Header>
<Data>...</Data>
</xml>
```

Based on the `<Type>` value, the `<Data>` element will have different elements. For e.g

```
<xml>
<Header><Type>Int</Type></Header>
<Data><Integer>10<Integer></Data>
</xml>

<xml>
<Header><Type>Str</Type></Header>
<Data><String>JAXB Test</String></Data>
</xml>
```

The Java classes will be

```
class TypeEntity { }

class IntEntity extends TypeEntity { }

class StrEntity extends TypeEntity { }
```

I want to use JAXB to parse the xml and create the sub classes accordingly. How I can do this? Please help me.

EDIT: Actually I will get these XML from a web service. After receiving I need to convert these as Java classes. Right now I am using DOM parser to identify the Type and instantiating the Java sub classes. I want to know is there any better way of doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write XSD schema for your XML document that JAXB could generate objects from it.

If you do not familiar with XSD check [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c19441/Understanding-XSD-Schema.htm).

Or you can use some XML tools to generate schema from XML. Just search XML to XSD or etc.

When you have the correct XSD schema of document you need to use some kind of script to generate objects using JAXB. I prefer ANT.

Example:

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" excludes="ant.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<xjc schema="${src.main.resources}/YourXSDSchema.xsd" destDir="${your.output.dir}" package="your.package">
    <produces dir="${your.output.dir}/your/package" includes="**/*" />
</xjc>
```

Then compile generated classes, pack them into the `.jar` and thats it.